# No CSS and JS loading on Wordpress site after enabling plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

Quick question: as someone who is using Wordpress a lot, I am first time ever noticing that I can't see any Javascript files **associated with my plugin (ULike plugin)** on my website when I enable that specific plugin. The HTML is loaded, but CSS and JS files are entirely missing and thus not loaded on the page...

I ran out of options. I already removed cache, enabled debug mode in Wordpress (didn't give any errors), checked the console and logs...

Any idea what might cause this error and what else I can do to check what is going wrong?

Comment: What is your plugin? What is your version of WordPress? Can you show source code?

Comment: is there any other plugins too?

Comment: Yes. Using multiple plugins, but this was specifically about ULike. I just downloaded the plugin via the repo. Nothing special and just business as usual, but I guess my custom theme is breaking it. When I add the CSS and JS manually, most of the plugins do work. Weird weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to my own question. It was because `<?php wp_head() ?>` was not added in my header.php that is was not working.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It might be an error with your URL ( www ) while loading CSS and JS.
Fixing all the links of CSS and JS should work.